# If WireMock query is not matched then defaults to overlapping endpoint instead of 404

Tags: java, json, wiremock

Here are two endpoints

Endpoint 1

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPath": "/event/event410"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 410,
    "jsonBody": {"status":"Error","message":"Target resource is no longer available - type 410 -"},
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

Endpoint 2

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPath": "/event/event410",
    "queryParameters":{
          "date": {
            "equalTo" : "SomeDate"
        }
      }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 410,
    "jsonBody": {"status":"Error","message":"Target resource is no longer available - type and date 410 -"},
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

If I hit the second endpoint with a query that does not match `SomeDate` then I expect it throw a `404 NOT FOUND` but instead it hits the 1st endpoint by default. Is there some way of specifying it such that it does not hit the overlapping endpoint. I have tried the priority attribute but it does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly declare the query parameter to be absent in the first stub by adding this:

`"queryParameters" : {
  "date" : {
    "absent" : true
  }
}`

Comment: Oh right that makes sense. I will give that a go when I return to the project. Thanks Tom!